# Steam/Steamcmd keeps segfaulting on Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: kubuntu, steam, 16.10, segmentation-fault

This is my first question here so sorry if I sound dumb.

I'm using Kubuntu 16.10, and when I try to log in to Steam's client the app just crashes. Trying to run it in a terminal just results in it segfaulting and dumping the core.

Same goes with steamcmd. I used

```
sudo apt-get install steam steamcmd
```

Now with steamcmd, I can launch it, it updates normally, and when I try to download a game it will download about 4% of it and then it'll segfault. The output of steamcmd looks like this:

```
Steam>/home/<me>/.steam/steamcmd/steamcmd.sh: line 38:  4224 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $DEBUGGER "$STEAMEXE" "$@"
```

I'm using the proprietary Intel firmware microcode and the proprietary nVidia drivers, for what it's worth. Any help on this matter is appreciated.

**EDIT:** I reinstalled steam via apt-get, and now instead of segfaulting, after the initial update steam simply exits. Trying to launch it again from the terminal results in the message `"Couldn't find bootstrap, it's not safe to reset Steam. Please contact technical support."`